# IIS 7.5: Initial request to website never gets loaded

Tags: web, iis-7.5, recycle

When I browse my website first time, internet keeps spinning/loading. If I two seconds later try to load it again, everything works fine.

It's like it's "sleeping".

I think it must have something to do with "recycling". I have set "Idle time-out" to 0 and Recycling "Regular time interval" to 0.

Before I browse my website, I take a look at "Worker process" and it says that the app pool process is running.

Any idea why my website "falls asleep"?

Thanks!
Mojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ASP.NET pages are compiled the first time they are requested (see ["Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)). So this might be the issue why your first request takes so long.

To avoid that, you can precompile your ASP.NET application:

- [How to: Precompile ASP.NET Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. :) By initial request I mean if I browse my website now ... and I leave it for a couple of hours and then browse it again, then it still keeps spinning/loading without showing the page. So the page is compiled, it's just "sleeping". Any idea why?

Comment: Well, I would first check if recycling of the app pool is really your issue here. Specify that IIS should log an event when an application pool is recycled and check into it.