# IIS 7.5 initial request to server never gets loaded

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5

I'm have trouble getting a project at work to run. The problem is that the server (IIS) never responds. When I use the chrome developer tools I can see that the GET request is just pending, and it stays pending until I close the window or stop the process.

So, I made a sample project, a simple .net 4 web application, and compiled it. Everything went fine when i ran it in VS2010, but when I tried to access it from my browser, I got the same problem as with the original work project. So it is not just a problem with one project, and that's why I think there is something wrong with the IIS settings. I know the port IIS listens on is ok and I've checked all the settings I can find.

I've looked through stackoverflow and googled it, but I have found no solution.
Can anyone help me with this?

The IIS version is 7.5.

Comment: you have to pre-compile your website.refer this one<br/>
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050025/iis-7-5-initial-request-to-website-never-gets-loaded?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050025/iis-7-5-initial-request-to-website-never-gets-loaded?rq=1

Comment: @Ravindrabagale It is compiled, I have already tested that in Visual Studio. It does not help to refresh the page a second time, I have already read that question, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after 1 day of troubleshooting. Earlier I had a problem with IIS not having permission to read the web.config file, so I set the permission on that file. As it turns out,  IIS didn't have permission to read anything else in the folder, so it couldn't read the files it needed to serve the page. Because it could read the web.config file I didn't get any error messages.

I just set the IIS_IUSRS user permissions to read on the whole project folder.

Comment: You also need to add the IUsr to the folder too as mentioned in this post, to prevent the access denied message:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418669/hosting-asp-net-in-iis7-gives-access-is-denied